# Complexity of Knuth's algorithm for variance

Tags: algorithm, complexity-theory, time-complexity, asymptotic-complexity

The algorithm is this:

```
def online_variance(data):
    n = 0
    mean = 0
    M2 = 0

    for x in data:
        n = n + 1
        delta = x - mean
        mean = mean + delta/n
        M2 = M2 + delta*(x - mean)

    if (n < 2):
        return 0

    variance = M2/(n - 1)
    return variance
```

taken from [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Algorithms_for_calculating_variance#Incremental_algorithm).

The question is which is the Time Complexity of this algorithm? My answer would be O(N), but it seems too easy. Am I missing something? Maybe the divisions should be also taken into account?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are right, the complexity is O(n). The statements in the for loop execute in constant time, and are executed n times (where n is the number of elements in data).